# Please add support of cyrillic tags

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, tags

I know that there are sites that have support for tags that use non-Latin alphabet, for instance Russian.SE (both sites), [Japanese.Stackexchange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags?page=12&tab=popular), etc.

Could this support be added to this site as well?

Comment: Related: http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/7/should-tag-names-be-in-english-or-in-ukrainian

Comment: This is coming. Stand by.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags now support Cyrillic text. Enjoy!

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. Is there easy way to soften (increase) the limit for tag length? Because as one of possible local policies for tagging we consider [creating bilingual tags like "orthography-орфографія"](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/13/4) — but 25 character is certainly too little for that solution.

Comment: @Sasha No that would not be trivial change to the UI. Incidentally, I think cramming dual-languages into each tag will be a poor idea in actual practice. Better to standardize on one language like every other language site and use synonyms. It's a much less kludge-y solution in my opinion.